# Divergence of series sin(1/n)

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Since $-1 \le \sin(1/n)\le 1$

and

$\lim_{n\to \infty} -1$ $\neq$ $\lim_{n\to \infty} 1$

can I use the nth-term test to prove that the series will diverge?

I've only seen the problem done using the limit comparison test and am not sure if I can use the nth-term test.

Comment: You must be misapplying some test here (I'm not sure what the $n$th term test is). You are correct that $\sum \sin(1/n)$ diverges, but note that $-1 \le \frac{1}{n^2} \le 1$ as well, but $\sum \frac 1 {n^2}$ converges.

Comment: @User8128 check this out: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test

Comment: More accurately $\sin x\sim_0x$ (in the sense of equivalence of functions near $0$).

Comment: Use that $\sin(1/n) = \frac{\sin(1/n)}{1/n}\cdot\frac 1 n$ and $\frac{\sin x}x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @Harry Gotcha. I've always called this the divergence test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not valid.  Indeed, note that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(1/n)=0$$

So it passes the $n$th term test.  However, it does diverge.  Note that:

$$n\ge1\implies\sin(1/n)\ge\frac{\sin(1)}n$$

So we may use the direct comparison test.

Comment: @MarkViola Actually, I just used the fact that for any function concave or convex over an interval $(a,b)$, then, $f(x)$ is bounded by its secant lines and tangent lines.  Very helpful trick.

Answer (score 10):

For $0\le x\le \pi/2$, the sine function is bounded by

$$\frac2\pi x\le \sin(x)\le x$$

Therefore, we assert that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sin\left(\frac1n\right) \ge \frac2\pi \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n$$

And hence, by comparison with the harmonic series, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac1n\right)$ diverges.

Comment: My favorite inequality, really shows that $\sin x$ is basically $x$ for small $x$